# Bootstrap CSS overwriting my custom CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pug, stylus

I am using Twitter Bootstrap's CSS and for some reasons it overwrites some of my classes.

First I load it before my custom CSS (I am using jade and stylus template engines):
HTML header:

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css')
```

in my HTML body:

```
table.table.table-striped
  thead
    th some items
    th some items
    th some items
  tbody
    tr
      td.table__td 
        a.table__link(href='/') some items
    tr
      td.table__td 
        a.table__link(href='/') some items
    tr
      td.table__td 
        a.table__link(href='/') some items
```

CSS:

```
.table__td
  padding 0
```

However I get the original 8px padding on my table td:

[image]

How can this happen?

Many thanks

Comment: google 'css selector specificity'

Comment: you are missing brackets?

Comment: There is a great explanation here: [Specifics on css specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because bootstrap's css declaration is not only

```
.table td /*specificity = 0 1 1*/
```

but

```
.table > tbody> tr > td /*specificity = 0 1 3*/
```

So the CSS selector specificity of Bootstrap is bigger than yours.

If you want your rule to be applied, you have to have a bigger specificity (or same level, but declared after the bootstrap one) to overwrite the bootstrap style.

Ex:

```
.table > tbody> tr > td.table__td{ /*specificity = 0 2 3*/
  padding:0;
}
```

or simply :

```
.table > td.table__td{  /*specificity = 0 2 1*/
  padding:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because bootstrap has higher **CSS precedence** due to its specificity.

http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

http://www.alternategateways.com/tutorials/css/css-101/part-four-the-css-order-of-precedence

**Solution**

Change your CSS rule to:

```
.table > tbody > tr > td.table__td
```

Comment: This rule won't work because the cells aren't in the `thead` but in the `tbody` !

Answer (score 0):

This is because bootstrap has a more specific declaration. 
Use this: `.table>....>td`. if you can't do that, use `!important`: `.table td{padding:0!important}`.

Comment: `!important` in this instance is a hack which will bite the OP back in the future, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try

.table > tbody > tr > td.table__td {
    padding 0}