# Bootstrap overrides custom CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Out of nowhere Bootstrap suddenly started overriding the custom CSS. The site has worked perfectly in about one month, then I updated the favicons, and everything started to mess up.

I tried to solve the problem by updating to the newest Boostrap (version 4). Also included everything correctly. Bootstrap CSS is being loaded before my custom CSS. However, the problem is still there.

**Header**

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Load jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Style.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/style.css">
```

**Example**

The easiest place to show where Bootstrap overrides my CSS is with the style `.btn`.

In my custom CSS I have set up the following: (loaded from style.css:936)

```
.btn {
  border-radius: 0px;
}
```

In the browser .btn is showing up like this: (loaded from bootstrap.css?ver=2.3:2618)

```
.btn {
   border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this problem? It's pretty strange that everything worked perfectly for a long time before I updated the favicons.

**The page can be found here:** http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/

Comment: Because you use a class the same as what Bootstrap uses, and Bootstrap has higher CSS precedence because of its [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Also refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142598/bootstrap-css-overwriting-my-custom-css)

Comment: From what I see in a .btn in the chrome console bootstrap doesn't override your css. 
Your css is also loaded correctly after bootstrap's css. 
My guess is that your browser cached the css file and you don't see some edits you made. 
Try changing your css link to `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/css/style.css?v=1.2">`

Comment: Could be, but then it shouldn't work on my other sites either. This is the only site that this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. Tried that, but nothing happends.

Comment: You could always try adding !important to make sure your css gets precedence like `border-radius: 0px !important;`

Comment: Yes, that is an option. But I would not like add !important to all my custom CSS. For one reason it would take alot of time, but at one point I would like to override this style again later in the stylesheet. Also it would slow down the loading time and so on.

Comment: Ok I believe I found your problem. If you go at line 173 of your page source you'll see this `<link rel='stylesheet' id='toolset_bootstrap_styles-css'  href='http://www.snekkergrytvik.no/wp-content/plugins/layouts/toolset/toolset-common/res/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css?ver=2.3' type='text/css' media='screen' />`. This is loaded after you declare your css so it takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed your source code the "style.css" file appearing before "bootstrap.css" file. That's why "style.css" loosing priority because last code of same selector will remove all before priority. "bootstrap.css" you added in 173 no lines but "style.css" added in 99 no lines that's why this happening.

Comment: Thank you. That is correct. Turns out there is a plugin which loads Bootstrap Layouts. When I disable that the plugin should load Boostrap everything crashes. But you found the problem. Thank you.